# Selected names and summed values in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have a data like this:

```
**NAME**          NUMBER
AUDE               8
STEPHANE           7
AUDE               2
STEPHANE           8
BERTRAND           1
```

How to define the expressions in QLikview to select the names we want to see and that should be distinct (showing the sum of all its NUMBERs)?

Like that:

```
**NAME**          NUMBER
AUDE               10
BERTRAND           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to hard-code some values in the expression in chart/table so it show the number only for them. If this is the case then you can use `set analysis` to do this:

`= sum ( {< [**NAME**] = { 'AUDE', 'BERTRAND' } >} NUMBER )`

There is a lot of info about `set analysis` around.

Check this video for quick introduction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMQJnKMkfxg ( its for Qlik Sense but the same rules are applied in Qlikview )

Comment: Tank you, but without number, if we want show a specific string like just 'Bertrand' ? wich function?

Comment: You want it to be dynamic? For example: type the string in some input box and this string to be applied in the chart expression ?

Comment: I'm sorry for my english, NO, just specify wich string i want to see, for example I want just specify in expression To see the String 'Bertrand' forget about sum. thanks

Comment: `= only ( {< [**NAME**] = { 'BERTRAND' } >} [**NAME**] )` 
Is it possible to share the qvw file somewhere ( no need to be with the original data ) so i can see your case

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.